# Why is 2-methyloxirane not named 1-methyloxirane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

The image above depicts 2-methyloxirane. Shouldn't the numbering be so that the methyl substituent receives the lowest number, being 1?

So shouldn't the name should be 1-methyloxirane?

Comment: Ethyl substituent gets the lowest number.

Answer (score 7):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, heteromonocyclic parent structures with three through ten ring members and containing one or more heteroatoms are generally named by using the [extended Hantzsch-Widman system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hantzsch%E2%80%93Widman_nomenclature); however, retained names are preferred for several heteromonocyclic compounds. When a single heteroatom is present in the ring, it is assigned the locant ‘1’.

> **P-22.2.2.1** Constructing and numbering Hantzsch-Widman names
>
> **P-22.2.2.1.1** (…) The presence of a single heteroatom determines the numbering in a monocyclic compound; the heteroatom has the locant ‘1’ and the numbering usually proceeds clockwise, when unsubstituted.
>   (…)

Therefore, the oxygen atom in oxirane has the locant ‘1’.

[image: oxirane]

This numbering is also used in substituted heteromonocyclic compounds. The heteroatom keeps the locant ‘1’; then low locants are given to the substituent prefixes. If there is still a choice, the lowest locant is given to the prefix cited first in the name.

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (a) fixed numbering in chains, rings, or ring systems, i.e., when the numbering of a system is fixed, for example in purine, anthracene, and phenanthrene, this numbering must be used, both in PINs and in general nomenclature;
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Therefore, the oxygen atom in **2-methyloxirane** has the locant ‘1’ according to (a), and then the lowest possible locant ‘2’ is given to the methyl substituent according to (f).

[image: 2-methyloxirane]

Accordingly, the oxygen atom in **2-ethyl-3-methyloxirane** has the locant ‘1’ according to (a), which leaves the locants ‘2’ and ‘3’ for the substituents. According to (g), the compound is named 2-ethyl-3-methyloxirane rather than 3-ethyl-2-methyloxirane since the prefix ‘ethyl’ is cited first in the name.

[image: 2-ethyl-3-methyloxirane]

Answer (score -4):

The name goes by the highest priority carbon 2,3.

ethyl side=>  ring carbon connected to a carbon has more priority C,H,H
methyl side=> ring carbon connected to a carbon has less priority H,H,H

That's why you should give number 2 to the ethyl.

Comment: No, the Cahn-Ingold-Prelog system is *not* used to determine the locant numbers. Ethyl comes before methyl simply because of alphanumerical ordering: E comes before M in the alphabet